# Timing between notifying that I am quitting and background check?

Tags: job-offer, notice-period, background-check

I accepted a job offer but it is contingent on a background check.  In the offer letter, the start date is 2 weeks from now.  I did not lie about anything on my resume, but I am always a bit paranoid about accidently making a mistake on my resume or just something out of my control happening.

I want to give my current employer two weeks of notice out of respect.  Pushing back the start date may be tough as well since they onboard only on Mondays and starting in November means I miss out in open enrollment it seems like.

Should I ask my new employer when they expect the background check to be done?  Would this make me look bad?  **Is this usual for an applicant to check up on**.  My record should be spotless but I am paranoid stuff out of my control, same with the paranoia that I get framed for something I didn't do.

Thanks!

Comment: There should always be an open enrollment period when you start a new job, if you're in the USA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Tell them that you need to give your current employer notice and ask them when they expect to have the results of the background check.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know if it would come off poorly if I asked.